# keras batchnorm layer moving average for variance

Tags: tensorflow, keras, batch-normalization

I've been trying to understand the Keras BatchNorm layer behavior in my Keras NN model. One question I encountered was how the BN layer is calculating the moving average of the 'variance'. My understanding is Keras is using exponential-weighted-average method to calculate the moving average for both mean and variance from the training mini-batches. But regardless of this, after a really large number of epochs, this moving average should approach the mean/variance of the training data set. But in my simple example, the 'variance' moving average is always different from the training data 'variance'. Below is my code and output:

```
from keras.layers import Input, BatchNormalization
from keras.models import Model
from keras.optimizers import Adam, RMSprop

import numpy as np

X_input = Input(shape=(6,))
X = BatchNormalization(axis=-1)(X_input)

model = Model(inputs=X_input, outputs=X)

model.compile(optimizer=RMSprop(), loss='mean_squared_error')

np.random.seed(3)
train_data = np.random.random((5,6))
train_label = np.random.random((5,6))

model.fit(x=train_data, y=train_label, epochs=10000, batch_size=6, verbose=False)

bn_gamma, bn_beta, bn_mean, bn_var = model.layers[1].get_weights()
train_mean = np.mean(train_data, axis=0)
train_var = np.var(train_data, axis=0)

print("train_mean: {}".format(train_mean))
print("moving_mean: {}".format(bn_mean))
print("train_var: {}".format(train_var))
print("moving_var: {}".format(bn_var))
```

Below is the output:

```
train_mean: [0.42588575 0.47785879 0.32170309 0.49151921 0.355046   0.60104636]
moving_mean: [0.4258843  0.47785735 0.32170165 0.49151778 0.35504454 0.60104346]
train_var: [0.03949981 0.05228663 0.04027516 0.02522536 0.10261097 0.0838988 ]
moving_var: [0.04938692 0.06537427 0.05035637 0.03153942 0.12829503 0.10489936]
```

If you see, the train_mean is the same as the moving average mean of BN layer, but train_var (variance) is not. Can anyone please help here? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the [source code of batchnorm](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/layers/normalization.py#L191), you can see that the unbiased estimator of population variance is used, here is the relevant line:

```
variance *= sample_size / (sample_size - (1.0 + self.epsilon))
```

In your case, the sample size is 5, so you should have `train_var * 5./4 == moving_var`, which is the case.

Comment: Thanks for the answer mpariente and the pointer to the source code!  I was also suspecting the unbiased version of variance actually but I was mistakenly using 6/5 instead of 5/4 at a late night ...

Comment: I did exactly the same mistake at first because of the batch_size. By the way, why using a batch_size of 6 if you only have 5 samples?

Comment: The batch_size = 6 is exactly the same mistake of thinking my sample size is 6 instead of 5 :-)

Comment: Reading the source code further, I am seeing the following:         
# If the learning is either dynamic, or set to training:
        normed_training, mean, variance = K.normalize_batch_in_training(
            inputs, self.gamma, self.beta, reduction_axes,
            epsilon=self.epsilon)
So it looks to me in training, the variance is using the biased version. So why does the moving average use the unbiased version? Any thought? @mpariente

Comment: During training, only the current batch's mean and variance are used to normalize the input. In the same time, the layer is accumulating the statistics which will be used at inference time. The fact that the correction on the variance is done only for CNTK backend probably has something to do with how the different backends compute the moments. But I cannot provide the difference, so I don't know exactly what the code is doing sorry.